# Software raid problem

Tags: linux, software-raid, iostat

We have a software raid on our server and we have a problem with disk performances. From time to time disk i/o freezes. During those periods `iostat` shows that one disk is faster than another. Both disks have the same manufacturer and type. Does this mean a hardware problem?

```
root@roubaix:~# iostat -p -x 1

...

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0.50    0.00    6.74    0.00    0.00   92.76

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sdb               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sdb1              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sdb2              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sdb3              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sda               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sda1              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sda2              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sda3              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
md2               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0.25    0.00    6.19   10.86    0.00   82.70

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sdb               0.00     8.00    0.00  800.00     0.00  5636.00    14.09    49.00   61.24    0.00   61.24   0.66  52.40
sdb1              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sdb2              0.00     8.00    0.00  800.00     0.00  5636.00    14.09    49.00   61.24    0.00   61.24   0.66  52.40
sdb3              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sda               0.00     9.00    0.00  646.00     0.00  4908.00    15.20   138.72  179.63    0.00  179.63   1.50  96.80
sda1              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sda2              0.00     9.00    0.00  646.00     0.00  4908.00    15.20   138.72  179.63    0.00  179.63   1.50  96.80
sda3              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
md2               0.00     0.00    0.00 1529.00     0.00 14708.00    19.24     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0.13    0.00    3.67   12.26    0.00   83.94

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sdb               0.00     2.00    0.00  448.00     0.00  3344.00    14.93     0.72    1.60    0.00    1.60   0.09   4.00
sdb1              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sdb2              0.00     2.00    0.00  448.00     0.00  3344.00    14.93     0.72    1.60    0.00    1.60   0.09   4.00
sdb3              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sda               0.00     2.00    0.00  450.00     0.00  2904.00    12.91   144.19  292.60    0.00  292.60   2.22 100.00
sda1              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sda2              0.00     2.00    0.00  450.00     0.00  2904.00    12.91   144.19  292.60    0.00  292.60   2.22 100.00
sda3              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
md2               0.00     0.00    0.00  155.00     0.00  3432.00    44.28     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0.38    0.00    3.78   18.89    0.00   76.95

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sdb               0.00     1.00    0.00  320.00     0.00  6372.00    39.83     0.64    2.01    0.00    2.01   0.09   2.80
sdb1              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sdb2              0.00     1.00    0.00  320.00     0.00  6372.00    39.83     0.64    2.01    0.00    2.01   0.09   2.80
sdb3              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sda               0.00     1.00    0.00  320.00     0.00  4236.00    26.48   143.48  442.86    0.00  442.86   3.12 100.00
sda1              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sda2              0.00     1.00    0.00  320.00     0.00  4236.00    26.48   143.48  442.86    0.00  442.86   3.12 100.00
sda3              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
md2               0.00     0.00    0.00    4.00     0.00    16.00     8.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0.51    0.00    3.29   18.23    0.00   77.97

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sdb               0.00     4.00    0.00  107.00     0.00  2812.00    52.56     0.20    1.87    0.00    1.87   0.11   1.20
sdb1              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sdb2              0.00     4.00    0.00  107.00     0.00  2812.00    52.56     0.20    1.87    0.00    1.87   0.11   1.20
sdb3              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sda               0.00     4.00    0.00  216.00     0.00  5164.00    47.81   112.01  569.59    0.00  569.59   4.63 100.00
sda1              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sda2              0.00     4.00    0.00  216.00     0.00  5164.00    47.81   112.01  569.59    0.00  569.59   4.63 100.00
sda3              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
md2               0.00     0.00    0.00    1.00     0.00     4.00     8.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0.25    0.00    6.26    1.88    0.00   91.61

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sdb               0.00     0.00    0.00    1.00     0.00     4.00     8.00     0.02   24.00    0.00   24.00  24.00   2.40
sdb1              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sdb2              0.00     0.00    0.00    1.00     0.00     4.00     8.00     0.02   24.00    0.00   24.00  24.00   2.40
sdb3              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sda               0.00     0.00    0.00   43.00     0.00   956.00    44.47     7.56  779.26    0.00  779.26   4.74  20.40
sda1              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sda2              0.00     0.00    0.00   43.00     0.00   956.00    44.47     7.56  779.26    0.00  779.26   4.74  20.40
sda3              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
md2               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00

Tue Apr 14 13:38:48 UTC 2015
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0.38    0.00    4.91    0.38    0.00   94.33

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sdb               0.00     0.00    1.00    0.00     4.00     0.00     8.00     0.03   28.00   28.00    0.00  28.00   2.80
sdb1              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sdb2              0.00     0.00    1.00    0.00     4.00     0.00     8.00     0.03   28.00   28.00    0.00  28.00   2.80
sdb3              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sda               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sda1              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sda2              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sda3              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
md2               0.00     0.00    1.00    0.00     4.00     0.00     8.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
```

ADDED:

There is nothing related to hard disks in `/var/log/kern.log`, nor in `/var/log/messages`. I am attaching the complete output of `smartctl -a /dev/sda` (I've run `smartctl -t long /dev/sda` two days ago). I do not fully understand the output but the error reported at `lifetime: 297 hours (12 days + 9 hours)` was there even before I've started long test. Thanks.

```
root@roubaix:~# smartctl -a /dev/sda
smartctl 5.41 2011-06-09 r3365 [x86_64-linux-3.2.0-4-amd64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-11 by Bruce Allen, http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     TOSHIBA DT01ACA200
Serial Number:    5386DM9GS
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000039 ff3d1011d
Firmware Version: MX4OABB0
User Capacity:    2,000,398,934,016 bytes [2.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   8
ATA Standard is:  ATA-8-ACS revision 4
Local Time is:    Tue Apr 14 14:22:29 2015 UTC
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x84) Offline data collection activity
                                        was suspended by an interrupting command from host.
                                        Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                                        without error or no self-test has ever 
                                        been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:                (15109) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:                    (0x5b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                                        Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                                        Suspend Offline collection upon new
                                        command.
                                        Offline surface scan supported.
                                        Self-test supported.
                                        No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                                        Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                                        power-saving mode.
                                        Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                                        General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:        (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:        ( 252) minutes.
SCT capabilities:              (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                                        SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                                        SCT Feature Control supported.
                                        SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000b   100   100   016    Pre-fail  Always       -       65536
  2 Throughput_Performance  0x0005   139   139   054    Pre-fail  Offline      -       73
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0007   157   157   024    Pre-fail  Always       -       291 (Average 191)
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       12
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   005    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000b   100   100   067    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0005   124   124   020    Pre-fail  Offline      -       33
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       6763
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   060    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       11
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       16
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       16
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0002   171   171   000    Old_age   Always       -       35 (Min/Max 13/47)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0008   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x000a   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       14

SMART Error Log Version: 1
ATA Error Count: 14 (device log contains only the most recent five errors)
        CR = Command Register [HEX]
        FR = Features Register [HEX]
        SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
        SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
        CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
        CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
        DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
        DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
        ER = Error register [HEX]
        ST = Status register [HEX]
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 14 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 297 hours (12 days + 9 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  84 51 01 c8 41 e7 0a  Error: ICRC, ABRT at LBA = 0x0ae741c8 = 182927816

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  61 08 00 c1 41 e7 40 00   6d+03:04:10.321  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  27 00 00 00 00 00 e0 00   6d+03:04:10.296  READ NATIVE MAX ADDRESS EXT
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 a0 00   6d+03:04:10.295  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ef 03 42 00 00 00 a0 00   6d+03:04:10.295  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]
  27 00 00 00 00 00 e0 00   6d+03:04:10.294  READ NATIVE MAX ADDRESS EXT

Error 13 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 297 hours (12 days + 9 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  84 51 01 88 41 79 09  Error: ICRC, ABRT at LBA = 0x09794188 = 158941576

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  61 08 58 c1 41 e7 40 00   6d+03:04:09.973  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 50 50 39 b9 94 40 00   6d+03:04:09.973  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 40 48 a9 45 79 40 00   6d+03:04:09.973  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 10 40 89 41 7b 40 00   6d+03:04:09.973  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 10 38 c1 41 7b 40 00   6d+03:04:09.973  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED

Error 12 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 297 hours (12 days + 9 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  84 51 01 c8 41 e7 0a  Error: ICRC, ABRT at LBA = 0x0ae741c8 = 182927816

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  61 10 20 c1 41 7b 40 00   6d+03:04:04.352  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 10 18 89 41 7b 40 00   6d+03:04:04.352  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 40 10 a9 45 79 40 00   6d+03:04:04.352  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 50 08 39 b9 94 40 00   6d+03:04:04.352  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 08 00 c1 41 e7 40 00   6d+03:04:04.352  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED

Error 11 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 297 hours (12 days + 9 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  84 51 01 88 41 79 09  Error: ICRC, ABRT at LBA = 0x09794188 = 158941576

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  61 08 58 c1 41 e7 40 00   6d+03:04:04.029  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 50 50 39 b9 94 40 00   6d+03:04:04.029  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 40 48 a9 45 79 40 00   6d+03:04:04.029  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 10 40 89 41 7b 40 00   6d+03:04:04.029  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 10 38 c1 41 7b 40 00   6d+03:04:04.029  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED

Error 10 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 297 hours (12 days + 9 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  84 51 01 c8 41 e7 0a  Error: ICRC, ABRT at LBA = 0x0ae741c8 = 182927816

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  61 10 20 c1 41 7b 40 00   6d+03:04:03.706  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 10 18 89 41 7b 40 00   6d+03:04:03.706  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 40 10 a9 45 79 40 00   6d+03:04:03.706  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 50 08 39 b9 94 40 00   6d+03:04:03.706  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 08 00 c1 41 e7 40 00   6d+03:04:03.706  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      6650         -
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      6620         -
# 3  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      6620         -
# 4  Short offline       Completed without error       00%       374         -
# 5  Short offline       Completed without error       00%       374         -
# 6  Short offline       Completed without error       00%       361         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Comment: Have you checked SMART with a command such as `smartctl -t long /dev/sda` followed (much) later by `smartctl -a /dev/sda`? Have you checked `/var/log/kern.log` or your equivalent for any errors reported by the kernel?

Comment: @roaima Thanks. I've added the output of `smartctl` to the question.

Comment: `/dev/sda` looks ok. But don't forget you need to to test the other disk, too